# How to trigger MathJax?

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I included `MathJax` with the script

```
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
```

This automatically replaces all math codes with the formatted tags.

1. How can I trigger `MathJax` by a javascript click only, instead of upon load.
2. How can I tell `MathJax` to put the formatted element at the end of the page instead of replacing the original code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### 1. How can I trigger MathJax by a javascript click only, instead of upon load.

From [docs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/hub.html):
`skipStartupTypeset: false`

> Normally MathJax will typeset the mathematics on the page as soon as the page is loaded. If you want to delay that process, in which case you will need to call `MathJax.Hub.Typeset()` yourself by hand, set this value to `true`.

---

[Starting typeset](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/typeset.html)

> The MathJax.Hub.Typeset() command also accepts a parameter that is a
>   DOM element whose content is to be typeset. That could be a paragraph,
>   or a  element, or even a MathJax math  tag. It could also
>   be the DOM id of such an object, in which case, MathJax will look up
>   the DOM element for you. So
>
> ```
> MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"MathExample"]);
> ```
>
> would typeset the mathematics contained in the element whose id is
>   MathExample. This is equivalent to
>
> ```
> var math = document.getElementById("MathExample");
> MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,math]);
> ```
>
> If no element or element id is provided, the whole document is
>   typeset.

```js
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    skipStartupTypeset: true,
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js", "TeX/AMSmath.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [["$", "$"]],
        processEscapes: true
    }
});

function startTypeSetting() {
  var HUB = MathJax.Hub;
  HUB.Queue(["Typeset", HUB, "render-me"]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
<p id="render-me">$a+b=c$<p>

<button onClick="startTypeSetting()">Start typesetting</button>
```

#### 2. How can I tell MathJax to put the formatted element at the end of the page instead of replacing the original code?

It would be better to know what are you trying to achieve, but here are 2 ways to skip typesetting for certain tags or classes, from [tex2jax preprocessors configs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/preprocessors/tex2jax.html):

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
     tex2jax: {
         skipTags: ["script","noscript","style","textarea","pre","code"],
         ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore_1|tex2jax_ignore_2"
    }
}
```

You can copy the content of element you want to render to another element and start typesetting there:

```js
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    skipStartupTypeset: true,
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js", "TeX/AMSmath.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [["$", "$"]],
        processEscapes: true
    }
});

function startTypeSetting() {
  //copy content from '#code-to-render' to '#render-point'
  var text = $('#code-to-render').val()
  $('#render-point').text(text)
  
  //Start typesetting
  var HUB = MathJax.Hub;
  HUB.Queue(["Typeset", HUB, "render-point"]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>

<textarea id="code-to-render">$a+b=c$</textarea>
<p id="render-point"></p>

<button onClick="startTypeSetting()">Start typesetting</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

For MathJax 3, it is:

```js
MathJax.typeset()
```