# MathJax not always rendering with Vue filtered list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mathjax

I'm trying to build a filtered list in Vue with equations rendered with MathJax, and it seems to be having some problems, since the equations renders on the first load, but when I search for terms, some equations render and some don't, I can't understand why.
Basically on the first load, if I type a character in my search bar, everything renders correctly, but when I search more, or erase it and do it again, it doesn't, as you can see in these images:

[image]
[image]

my Vue code is as follows:

```
var analisiMatematica = new Vue({

el: '#searcher',
data: {
    searchQuery: '',
    isResult: false,
    results: [],
    //json: 'json/analisimatematica.json',
    error: ''
},

mounted: function() {
    axios.get('./json/analisimatematica.json')
    .then(function(response) {
        this.results = response.data.Domande;
        console.log(this.results);
    }.bind(this))
    .catch(function(error) {
        this.error = error.data;
        console.log(error.data);
    }.bind(this));
},

methods: {
    removeSearchQuery: function() { 
      this.searchQuery = '';
      this.isResult = false;
    },
    submitSearch: function() {
      this.isResult = true;

    }
},
computed: {
    filteredObj: function() {
        var list = [];
        this.results.forEach(function(el) {
            if(el.domanda.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                list.push(el);
            }
        }.bind(this))
        return list;
    }
}


});
```

MathJax is loaded in my html file's `<head>` like this:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],

    }
  });
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
```

While the vue app section is like this:

```
<div id="searcher">
            <p v-show="error" v-html="error"></p>
            <form class="searchForm" v-on:submit.prevent="submitSearch">
                <input type="text" name="queryInput" v-model="searchQuery" placeholder="Che domanda cerchi?" @keyup="submitSearch">
                <span v-show="searchQuery" class="removeInput" @click="removeSearchQuery">+</span>
            </form>
            <div class="results" v-show="isResult">
                <ul>
                    <li v-for="result in filteredObj">
                        <p id="domanda">{{ result.domanda }}</p>
                        <p id="risposta">{{ result.risposta }}</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to [trigger MathJax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45762920) to render again when `filteredObj` is changed. Watch `filteredObj`:

```
watch: {
    filteredObj: function () {
      if ('MathJax' in window) {
        this.$nextTick(function() { 
           MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub, document.body])
        });
      }
    }
}
```

```js
var analisiMatematica = new Vue({
    el: '#searcher',
    data: {
        searchQuery: '',
        isResult: false,
        results: [],
        //json: 'json/analisimatematica.json',
        error: ''
    },
    
    mounted: function() {
            this.results = [{domanda: '$a+b=c$', risposta: '$a+b=c$'}]
    },
    
    methods: {
        removeSearchQuery: function() { 
          this.searchQuery = '';
          this.isResult = false;
        },
        submitSearch: function() {
          this.isResult = true;
    
        }
    },
    computed: {
        filteredObj: function() {
            var list = [];
            this.results.forEach(function(el) {
                if(el.domanda.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                    list.push(el);
                }
            }.bind(this))
            return list;
        }
    },
     watch: {
        filteredObj: function () {
          if ('MathJax' in window) {
            this.$nextTick(function() { 
               MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub, document.body])
            });
          }
        }
    }
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],

    }
  });
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>

<div id="searcher">
  <p v-show="error" v-html="error"></p>
  <form class="searchForm" v-on:submit.prevent="submitSearch">
      <input type="text" name="queryInput" v-model="searchQuery" placeholder="Che domanda cerchi?" @keyup="submitSearch">
      <span v-show="searchQuery" class="removeInput" @click="removeSearchQuery">+</span>
  </form>
  <div class="results" v-show="isResult">
      <ul>
          <li v-for="result in filteredObj">
              <p id="domanda">{{ result.domanda }}</p>
              <p id="risposta">{{ result.risposta }}</p>
          </li>
      </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It isn't able to find `window.MathJax`

Comment: Try `if ('MathJax' in window) {`

Comment: OK now it works, how should it be written without the arrow function? Cause it's triggering an error if I write it the classic way.

Comment: Just one thing,I feel like maybe I could get help here, since it can be related to mathjax, sometimes it happens in the render that another formula appears in the second row of an element, while the object contains the correct data (as checked in console), the page, shows me another string\formula that should not be there, as shown [here](https://i.imgur.com/211ueDR.png). You think is it mathjax related or it's another issue completely? I can't identify the problem, everything works correctly besides this little thing. @Orkhan Alikhanov