# stop mathjax from running itself

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I am using `mathjax3.1.2` with `async` on `script` tag. However, I find it running itself automatically on document loading and screw up my page since I have plain text that waits `marked.js` to render at first.

this is html content:

```html
equation_app.addEventListener('click', e=>{
  autofocus(e);
  let start = editor.selectionStart;
  let end = editor.selectionEnd;
  tagging('$', '$');
  editor.focus();
  if(editor.selectionStart === editor.selectionEnd)editor.selectionStart = editor.selectionEnd = start + 1;
  refresh();
});
```

which after marked rendered, it will be wrapped into a `<pre>` and `<code>` tag. But as MathJax running before it, it was messed up:

```html
equation_app.addEventListener('click', e=&gt;{
  autofocus(e);
  let start = editor.selectionStart;
  let end = editor.selectionEnd;
  tagging('<mjx-container class="MathJax CtxtMenu_Attached_0" jax="CHTML" role="presentation" tabindex="0" ctxtmenu_counter="0" style="font-size: 101.6%; position: relative;"><mjx-math class="MJX-TEX" aria-hidden="true"><mjx-msup><mjx-mi class="mjx-n"></mjx-mi><mjx-script style="vertical-align: 0.363em;"><mjx-mo class="mjx-n" size="s"><mjx-c class="mjx-c2032"></mjx-c></mjx-mo></mjx-script></mjx-msup><mjx-msup><mjx-mo class="mjx-n"><mjx-c class="mjx-c2C"></mjx-c></mjx-mo><mjx-script style="vertical-align: 0.363em;"><mjx-mo class="mjx-n" size="s"><mjx-c class="mjx-c2032"></mjx-c></mjx-mo></mjx-script></mjx-msup></mjx-math><mjx-assistive-mml role="presentation" unselectable="on" display="inline"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msup><mi></mi><mo>′</mo></msup><msup><mo>,</mo><mo>′</mo></msup></math></mjx-assistive-mml></mjx-container>');
  editor.focus();
  if(editor.selectionStart === editor.selectionEnd)editor.selectionStart = editor.selectionEnd = start + 1;
  refresh();
});
```

I did quite a lot research, seems that in version 2 `skipStartupTypeset`  configuration solves the problem, however removed in version 3.

refer to this post 4 years ago: [How to trigger MathJax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45762920/how-to-trigger-mathjax/45763146)

I seek for a way:

- disable mathjax from running itself at loading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply configure Mathjax 3 to not do typesetting on startup by setting the following in the config:

```
{
     startup: {
         typeset: false
     }
 }
```

Documentation: https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/startup/startup.html#the-configuration-block